# Dynamic dropdowns Selenium webdriver Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Recently started with selenium in python and so far only element I have problems with are Dynamic dropdowns. For example on [webpage](https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form) under  [Subjects and State and City](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWEMj.png). How to handle these elements that are not visible in DOM. Can please someone can show me how they would solve example mentioned above.

For subjets it failes on this line:

class SwitchToFrame():

```
def test1(self):
    baseUrl = "https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(baseUrl)

    wait = WebDriverWait(wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10, poll_frequency=1)
    element = wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='subjectsContainer']/div")))
    element.send_keys("English")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I proceeded to click the first option in Subject after inputting the English. Also if you do check the driver.page_source you can actually see the elements inside. It disappears after the handling of the input tag.

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form")
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#subjectsInput")))
element.send_keys("English")
print(driver.page_source)
elem=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "react-select-2-option-0")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", elem)
```

Imports

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Code works but in source i can see only react-select-3-input. Any tips for for searching elemnts like this?

Comment: It comes out when there is focus on the input tags. So you need to click the input tag first.